# Feature vector computation for a specific entity

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I'm working in this specific scenario:
I have a list of entities. Each entity (e) is described by a list of items L(e).
Each item (i) which belong to L(e), has a set of feature (in this case it is a URI) associated to it (e.g., supposing a feature vector whose size is N = 3: item1 = A1, B1, C2; item2 = A1, B2, C2; ...).

An item, in this specific case, could be represented by this vector:

```
| dbpedia-owl:director         | dbpedia-owl:producer // attributes' names

dbpedia:Quentin_Tarantino      |  dbpedia:Lawrence_Bender // attributes' values
```

I want to compute a representative vector (a centroid?) for each entity starting from the features vector of each item that belong to the entity's item list.
Can you suggest to me a way to compute it properly?

I need this kind of representation in order to be able to compute a similarity between the item (which can be done using the Jaccard Index of the properties) and a similarity between entity (in my case they are films). 
If I have a specific vector representation for a specific entity I will be able to compute a similarity score between item and entity too.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you include an example of exactly what the entity's item list looks like?

Comment: Sorry, but that's still pretty unclear, and it's not a list or a vector.

Comment: You can represent it as you wish. The important aspect is that each item could be represented by this two features (it's only an example, could be present more than 2 attribute): dbpedia-owl:director and dbpedia-owl:producer.

Comment: I'm still unclear as to what exactly you're trying to accomplish. what is the purpose of this "representation"? in what context would it be used? e.g. classification? clustering? something else? it would help if you could give example input and output (as you envision them)

Comment: I hope that now is clear